# Is possible to set the properties for the mock object before injectMocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, testing, mockito

I try to set some properties for the mock object before injecting them to the test class, but it doesn't work

**here is my code:**

```
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    private MyProperties myProperties;

    @Autowired
    private Properties properties;

    private final String id;
    private final String name;


    public MyClass(MyProperties myProperties){
        id = myProperties.getId();
        name = myProperties.getName();
    }

    public String Info(){
        return properties.getAddress();
    }
}
```

**here is my test:**

```
public class TestClass {

@Mock
private MyProperties myProperties;

@Mock
private Properties properties;

@InjectMocks
private MyClass testObject = new MyClass(myProperties);

@Before
public void setUp(){
    when(myProperties.getId()).thenReturn("1");
    when(myProperties.getUser()).thenReturn("user");
}

@Test
public void InfoTest(){
    when(properties.getAddress()).thenReturn("address");
    assertEquals("address", testObject.info());
}
}
```

It seems @injectMocks happens before setUp() method and @InjectMocks already help to instantiate an object of MyClass before when...thenReturn,  so it threw a NullPointerException

so, Is that possible to set the properties for the mock object before injectMock? anyone can help?

Comment: Surely just move private MyClass testObject = new MyClass(myProperties);
inside your setUp method as  testObject = new MyClass(myProperties); and keep the main testObject global..

Comment: it will throw an exception, Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'XXX' of type XXX'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : null, because it seems once the class marked with InjectMocks, it will call the constructor...I need to pass the argument to the constructor

Comment: REmove `@InjectMocks` and move the `new MuClass(myProperties)` to the setup method AFTER the `when` lines.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tried this way before, but If I use this in this way, another issue will occur, that is, the value of private Properties properties cannot be injected to the myClass, the test will fail in InfoTest because properties is null.

Comment: No it won't. The key is the ordering and not to use `@InjectMocks`.

Comment: Properties and myProperties are not the same things, I think If I don't inject them to MyClass object, this object will not own them as its attributes... so when I use myClass instance to call Info() method, it threw NullPointerException, properties here is null

Comment: Now you see why field injection is bad. Use constructor injection for both dependent classes.

Comment: @Tom I am not sure how to do contractor injecting, can you provide some ideas ?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/constructor-injection-in-spring

Comment: You may also consider changing your production code: calling any methos on the constructor parameters is a *code smell* and should be avoided. It hides the real dependencies of the class. So you should better either pass `ID` and `Name` as parameters of their own *or* store the whole `myProperties` parameter in an instance field instead of  `ID` and `Name` separately.